# Magento 2, Why filter of all customer grid in backend is not show?

Tags: magento2, backend

I have a problem about backend. 
When i click all customer menu for search customer. Filter is not show on header page.

It don't have any error in console or error log.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with clearing cache ? or open in the private window and check .if still issue is there then check your `console` or` error log` what error it throws ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check if below line of code is commented in your ui file **customer_listing.xml** under **`<listingToolbar name="listing_top">`**. This is responsible to show all available filters in customer UI grid.

```
<filters name="listing_filters"/>
```

The file path is vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component OR may be in your custom module being overwritten for customer. The whole code to display all the available options(buttons, filters, search etc)

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected customers?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="subscribe">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">subscribe</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscribe to Newsletter</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massSubscribe"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="unsubscribe">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">unsubscribe</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massUnsubscribe"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to unsubscribe selected customers from newsletter?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="assign_to_group">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">assign_to_group</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options</argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">customer/index/massAssignGroup</item>
                    <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to assign selected customers to new group?</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="edit">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **customer_listing.xml**, please check all columns.
"filter" attribute is not added in it. so we can not filter in it.